# adding an action inside if condition not working

Tags: filters, actions, conditional-tags, init

This is my function

```
$enable = false; //if false is provided then the action should run and remove the breadcrumbs

if($enable ===false){
      add_action( 'init', 'woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
    function woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
    }

  }
```

But it is not working as expected. Not able to figure out what went wrong?

---

I have tried echo "test"; it is getting returned but add action does not seems to work

It worked when :

```
if($enable ===false){

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
}
```

But not sure if this is correct thing to do.

Comment: When is `woocommerce_breadcrumb` originally hooked? You're removing it on `init` at priority `10`, but if WooCommerce hooks it later you will need to use a later hook to remove it. Also, the if condition should probably go _inside_ `woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie still confused. i have followed documentation only..they are also removing it on init, if i use the code outside the if condition the code perfectly works. if i change the code as updated question it works..but not sure if it the right thing to do